# Could not save In-app purchase in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I followed this tutorial for in-app purchase http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_In-App_Purchase_Tutorial

After running the app I could retrieve the product list and do purchase successfully. But when I stop running the app from Xcode and run once again it looks like the purchase is not saved, it makes me to purchase another time. How to save this purchase always even I exit from my app and open up once again? Please help

P.S - I'm trying to do a in-app for enabling app functionality in my existing app.

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the information that the In App has been unlock directly inside your application after the purchase.

You can easily do it by setting a specific key in user settings to check at launch if the additional feature has been unlock (although you may wish to do it with some more security and encryption).

Comment: -(void)enableLevel2
{
    _level2Button.enabled = YES;
    NSUserDefaults *saveapp = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [saveapp setBool:TRUE forKey:k_Save];
    [saveapp synchronize];
    
}***..then on view didload ...***  NSUserDefaults *saveapp = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    bool saved = [saveapp boolForKey:k_Save];
    if (!saved) {
        /// not save code here
    } else {
        ///saved code here
      //  Label.text = @"item has been purchased";
        
        NSLog(@"purchased");
    }
Is this correct ? @slecorne